# Hide a ng-repeat, if a child/nested repeat has a value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have multiple ng-repeats, that depend on each other.

```
$scope.niveaus = [
        { niveau: 'a' },
        { niveau: 'b' },
        { niveau: 'c' },
        { niveau: 'd' },
        { niveau: 'e' },
        { niveau: 'f' },
        { niveau: 'g' }
    ];

    $http.get('/goals.json').success(function(goals) {
        $scope.goals = goals;
    });
```

I fill hardcoded niveau A-G. In the Goals list I match the names of the niveaus, with that from the JSON.

And do a ng-repeat:

```
<ul ng-repeat="niveau in niveaus">

        <li class="foobar">{{ niveau.niveau }}</li>

        <div ng-repeat="goal in goals | unique:'niveau_id'">
            <div ng-if="goal.niveau.name == niveau.niveau">
                <li class="yes">{{ goal.niveau.name }}</li> 
            </div>
        </div>

    </ul>
```

So it checks for each niveau the goals. If a Goal matches the names, it will show.
But what the problem is now, is that li.foobar also is shown, if there is a match in the ng-if.

So this can be the output:

[image]

But it should have unique niveau names. *A-G for every row*. And show if a li.yes is there in the repeat part, it should hide the li.foobar from the repeat list.

But how to achieve that in Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Check docs on [filters](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

```
angular.module('myApp', []).filter('withgoals', function() {
return function(input, goals) {
  var out = [] 
  for (var i = 0; i < goals.length; i++) {
    if (input.niveau == goals[i].niveau.name) out.push(input[i])
  }
  return out;      
});


<div ng-repeat='n in niveaus| withgoals: goals'></div>
```

Comment: Then you're only getting the niveaus that have goals inside. I also wanna show the niveau when there is no goal inside. Every row should have the following: A B C D E F G.

Comment: @user1469734 add example data structure and resulting html layout to your question, as not it is not clear, as you do not show `goal` part of your data.